# Java EE 7 Automatic Timer (EJB Timer) not working for WildFly 8.1.0

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, timer, ejb, wildfly

I am following the [Using the Timer Service](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/ejb-basicexamples004.htm) tutorial to build a simple scheduled execution. Trying the automatic approach and using [WildFly 8.1.0 Final](http://wildfly.org/downloads/) for it.

**Session Bean**

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class HelloJob {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(HelloJob.class);

    public HelloJob() {
        logger.error(">>> Hello Job Created.");
    }

    @Schedule(second="*")
    public void sayHello() {
        logger.error(">>> Server Hello!");
    }

}
```

On deploy the class is properly instantiated printing the `>>> Hello Job Created.` message, but the method `sayHello()` is never called.

According to the tutorial the `@Schedule(second="*")` means that it should execute every second.

> Setting an attribute to an asterisk symbol (*) represents all
>   allowable values for the attribute.

Also only stateful session beans are not allowed for timers, and I am using a singleton, which is also used in the example.

> The timer service of the enterprise bean container enables you to
>   schedule timed notifications for all types of enterprise beans except
>   for stateful session beans.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `@Schedule(second="*", minute="*", hour="*")`.

the default values for hour and minute are "0" which can be quite irritating and effectively forces you to set these.